# Prevent user from opening two same child windows?

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light

A user clicks on menu item and a child window is shown (non-modal). How do I prevent user to not open the same window again?

I know I can handle initialize and Closed events of the child window to add.remove it to some collection of opened child windows, but I am looking at the pure and clean MVVM way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add one property to your view model class to handle visibility of a view, then bind it to your view. Inside setter section of you property check if its value is changed, if not just return.

You don't need to create a lot of child windows in your application, just control the visibility of existing one and change the data you want to show.